# Where should the authentication functionality for my website reside?

Tags: django

I'm making a workout calendar app where a person can register a user and start logging his workouts in a calendar. [image]

This is how the project is structured right now. Inside of **workoutcal/urls.py**, I've defined, among others, the following urls:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register')
```

The views that handle the requests reside in **workoutcal/views.py**. My question is if this is the right way to do it. I'm a little bit confused about what an "app" in django (such as the workoutcal app) encapsulates. I think I want user to log in to the whole functionality of my website, and if that is the case, shouldn't the login urls reside in **workout/urls.py**?

Comment: What is your question? You want an explanation on django app or login functionality in you django application?

Comment: My question is, where is the right place to put the login and register views?

Comment: Are you using any third party package to manage users?

Comment: I'm using stuff from django.contrib.auth, the rest I wrote myself.

Comment: Have a look at [Django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth).
It seamlessly manages user accounts, registrations and social authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics of where ***exactly*** authentication should be are not carved in stone (as every project is differently structured), but as a general rule it should look like this

- client sends login information to server
- server checks if login info is correct, then if it is, sends back a key unique to that login session/user (former is more secure)
- when client wants to access data only available to that user, it sends a request to server along with the key received upon login

If your method matches this pattern, and communication with the server is encrypted, the chances are it's good enough.